# Would it be technically possible to externalize `\include`d chapters

Tags: include, build-system

TikZ saves figures as separate PDFs to reuse and embed.
Would it be technically possible, for `\include`, to do something similar for the included content? I know I can already include PDFs (I never tried multi-page PDFs, but there's `pdfpages`), but external files (`.aux` and relatives) are not shared, so you couldn't have references across included chapters that way.

But it seems like you could try flushing those external files, building the external files with the same `\jobname` so that the same `.aux` files are reused, patching things so that the file isn't cleared, and including the output file.

This question is just about "would this be feasible without patching TeX, or can you see some obstacle"? Let's assume we're only dealing with external files from the LaTeX core for simplicity (`.aux`, `.lof`, `.lot`).
If preferred, I could make this a community-wiki question.

Comment: Source: this tweet https://twitter.com/chris__martin/status/893201510204571649

Comment: Can you clarify how this would be useful? If you have a large document and want to save compilation time, you can work on one chapter at a time, using `\includeonly` for example. Then, the lengthy step of compiling everything only has to happen at the end (or at least only now and then).

Comment: there was a very long series of questions asking about this at start of year (the answer is essentially no, not if you want hyperlinks and other features to work) there are not many cases it would be useful compared to the standard include, really.